# Setting up a full site page in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates, page-layout

I am just starting with CodeIgniter, but I can’t quite figure how to sort out my views.

I’ve made a sample layout explaining my problem, and is attached to this post.

I have a **menu box**, a **user-system** box and a **content** box.

In procedural PHP I would have a page called *index.php* with a parameter from *GET*, including the **content**. The **user-system** would just be included in the *index.php* file inside the box, and so would the **menu**.

How can I do this in a proper way using MVC and CodeIgniter?

[image]

Comment: where's your attachment?

Comment: It's updated now, thank you

Comment: still, things are not clear. what do you need exactly. View layout has nothing to do with CI. it's simple css. so can you specify your needs more.

Comment: We can call it View-grouping if you will. I need to have the same functionality using MVC and CI as if I was including each item on the index.php in procedural PHP

Comment: Tomek has a good point in his answer

Comment: I have modified my answer you can load multiple view pages like I given in answer... Let me know if you have any query. :)

Comment: FYI: CodeIgniter is still "procedural php". Just because your code has classes does not make it automatically OOP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Most Simple Template Library for CodeIgniter](http://maestric.com/doc/php/codeigniter_template). It allows you to do what you would do in your php example. Create a "main" view and channel your content to it using your controller(s). You can create "subthemes" for body, content, sidebars etc.

Comment: This lead me on the way. I ended up using a HMVC extension

Answer (score 1):

Hope you have configured codeigniter on your machine.

now create one file in controller folder 
for example :
D:\wamp\www\demoProject\application\controllers\homePage.php

add following code in homePage controller

```
    <?php

    class HomePage extends CI_Controller {

        var $controller = "homePage";        
        var $viewContent = array();              

        function list_homePage() {
```

// Load view pages
   // Load header view page

```
            $this->load->view('xome/header');
```

// Load main view page

```
            $this->load->view('xome/list_' . $this->controller, 
            $this->viewContent);
```

// Load footer view page

```
            $this->load->view('xome/footer');
        }
}
?>
```

after that create one file in view folder
for example :
D:\wamp\www\demoProject\application\views\list_homePage.php

put your html code in view file.

Hope this will help you... :)

Comment: I know how to create single view pages, what I need is a page where other pages is nested in

Answer (score 0):

For menu I would create a model like this:

```
class mMenu extends CI_Model{

 function mMenu(){
  parent::__construct();
 }

 function home(){
  $menu = array(
    'main_menu' => '<ul>
                      <li>Menu Link 1</li>
                      <li>Menu Link 2</li>
                      <li>Menu Link 3</li>
                    </ul>'
  );
  return $menu;
 }
}
```

In controller, say home:

```
function home(){
 $this->load->model('mMenu');
 $options['menu'] = $this->mMenu->home();

 $this->load->view('home_view', $options);
}
```

In the view file, wherever I need the menu to load:

```
echo $menu['main_menu'];
```

You should do something similar to control the state of the user and return the form if the user is not logged in and anything else if the user is logged in.